# How do I open another app using inAppWebview?

Tags: flutter

It is being developed as a flutter.
I implemented payment using inAppWebView.
But there are times when it moves well, and there are times when it doesn't.
What's wrong with my code?

I think it's from shouldOverrideUrlLoading
" await controller.stopLoading(); "
I think it's because of this part that it doesn't work and it doesn't work,
Intent processing is impossible without this part.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Vxg.png)

Intent processing refers to removing intents and matching schemes to open other apps, as you can see in the image.

If anyone has solved this problem, please give me a solution. Please

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:funcare/network/network_utils.dart';
import 'package:funcare/screens/mall/mall_main_screen.dart';
import 'package:funcare/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:kakao_flutter_sdk_user/kakao_flutter_sdk_user.dart';
import 'package:nb_utils/nb_utils.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import '../../main.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import '../../utils/extensions/uri_extensions.dart';
import '../community/c_alert.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:developer' as dev;

class _MallKspayState extends State<MallKspay> {
  InAppWebViewController? webViewController;

  final GlobalKey webViewKey = GlobalKey();

  late PullToRefreshController pullToRefreshController;
  double progress = 0;

  InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
        useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
      ),
      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
        useHybridComposition: true,
      ),
      ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
      ));

  @override
  void initState() {
    appStore.setLoading(false);
    super.initState();

    pullToRefreshController = PullToRefreshController(
      options: PullToRefreshOptions(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onRefresh: () async {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          webViewController?.reload();
        } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
          webViewController?.loadUrl(
              urlRequest: URLRequest(url: await webViewController?.getUrl()));
        }
      },
    );

    init();
  }

  bool isAppLink(Uri url) {
    final appScheme = url.scheme;

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      debugPrint("isIOS");
      return appScheme != 'http' &&
          appScheme != 'https' &&
          appScheme != 'about' &&
          appScheme != 'data';
    } else {
      debugPrint("isAndroid");
      return appScheme != 'http' &&
          appScheme != 'https' &&
          appScheme != 'about:blank' &&
          appScheme != 'data';
    }
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    afterBuildCreated(() {
      appStore.setLoading(false);
      //setStatusBarColor(context.primaryColor);
      debugPrint('benevento : afterBuildCreated');
    });
  }

  @override
  void setState(fn) {
    if (mounted) super.setState(fn);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget get trailing {
    //return ic_arrow_right.iconImage(size: 16);
    return const Icon(
      Icons.arrow_right,
      size: 16,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final jsonBody = jsonEncode(payData.toJson());
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "쇼핑 요금 결제",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              color: black,
              icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context); // 종료
              },
            ),
          ],
          bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(0),
              child: Container(
                color: context.dividerColor,
                height: 1.0,
              )),
        ),
        body: InAppWebView(
          key: webViewKey,
          initialOptions: options,
          pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
          onLoadStart: (controller, url) async {
            setState(() {});
            debugPrint('쇼핑 요금 결제 [onLoadStart]: $url');
            dev.log("쇼핑 요금 결제 [onLoadStart]: $url");
          },
          onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
            pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
            debugPrint('쇼핑 요금 결제 [onLoadStop]: $url');
            dev.log("쇼핑 요금 결제 [onLoadStop]: $url");
            final response = await controller.evaluateJavascript(
                source: "document.documentElement.innerText");
            Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = json.decode(response);
            String message = jsonResponse["message"];
            print("message: $message");
            // snackBar(context, title: message);

            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              isScrollControlled: true,
              builder: (context) {
                return Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "${message}!",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: mallColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20), // Add spacing between widgets
                        // Add more widgets here
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              // 터치 이벤트 발생 시 처리할 로직 작성
                              print("다른 상품 추가하기 버튼 클릭");
                              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => MallMainScreen(),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: Color(0xFF999999),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  top: 3,
                                  bottom: 3,
                                  left: 30,
                                  right: 30,
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  '홈 화면으로 이동하기',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xFF999999),
                                    fontSize: 14.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        // Add more widgets as needed
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
          androidOnPermissionRequest: (controller, origin, resources) async {
            return PermissionRequestResponse(
                resources: resources,
                action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
          },
          onLoadResourceCustomScheme: (controller, url) async {
            dev.log("[onLoadResourceCustomScheme]: $url");
            await controller.stopLoading();
            return null;
          },
          onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
            dev.log("[onLoadError]: $url");
            pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
          },
          onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
            if (progress == 100) {
              pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
              //appStore.setLoading(false);
            }
            setState(() {
              this.progress = progress / 100;
            });
          },
          onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
            debugPrint("url [onUpdateVisitedHistory]: ${url}");
          },
          onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) {
            debugPrint('$consoleMessage');
          },
          shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
            print(
                '====================shouldOverrideUrlLoading====================');

            var curUrl = navigationAction.request.url;
            // snackBar(context, title: curUrl.toString());
            debugPrint("curUrl : ${curUrl}");
            String ru = Uri.decodeComponent(curUrl.toString());
            debugPrint("ru : ${ru}");
            if (curUrl == null) return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
            var test = isAppLink(curUrl);
            print("test : ${test}");

            if (isAppLink(curUrl)) {
              await controller.stopLoading();
              debugPrint("1");
              var scheme = curUrl.scheme;
              debugPrint("scheme : ${scheme}");
              if (Uri.parse(ru).scheme == 'intent') {
                debugPrint("2");
                if (Platform.isAndroid) {
                  debugPrint("Android");
                  debugPrint("3");
                  Uri uriAndroid = UriExtension.androidIntentUrlOrigin(ru);
                  debugPrint('android extension uri : $uriAndroid');
                  snackBar(context, title: uriAndroid.toString());
                  if (await canLaunchUrl(uriAndroid)) {
                    debugPrint('canLaunch');
                    await launchUrl(uriAndroid);
                    if (uriAndroid.scheme == 'https' ||
                        uriAndroid.scheme == 'http') {
                      await launchUrl(uriAndroid);
                      debugPrint("4");
                    } else {
                      await launchUrl(uriAndroid);
                      debugPrint("5");
                      return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                    }
                    debugPrint("6");
                  } else {}
                }
              } else {
                debugPrint("8");
                debugPrint("iOS 진입");
                if (Platform.isIOS) {
                  debugPrint("iOS");
                  if (![
                    "http",
                    "https",
                    "file",
                    "chrome",
                    "data",
                    "javascript",
                    "about"
                  ].contains(curUrl.scheme)) {
                    debugPrint("curUrl.scheme");
                    if (await canLaunchUrl(curUrl)) {
                      // Launch the App
                      await launchUrl(curUrl);
                      // and cancel the request
                      return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                    }
                  }
                  return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                }
              }
              debugPrint("7");
              return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
            } else {
              return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
            }
          },
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this does not answer your question but generally it is a bad practice to open a payment page in an embedded web view and it raises a lot of security concerns!

Comment: On a second note, I think your intent should look something like this
`intent://pay?srCode=0613325&kb-acp://#Intent;scheme=kb-acp;package=com.kbcard.cxh.appcard;end;`